# Why I cannot access wdPropertyComments in VIsual Studio?

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2013

I paste the following code to visual studio 2013, but it alerts me that wdPropertyComments is not declared

I do the similar thing in VBA in Microsoft Word and it works, why that happen?

By the way , in VBA in MS word, we can use activedocument, but how to use activedocument inside visual studio?

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    ' ReadOnly Property ActiveDocument As Document
    Public Sub Application_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
            ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.DocumentBeforeSave
        If SaveAsUI = True Then
            Dim intResponse As Integer
            intResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to generate Jats XML file?", vbYesNo)
            If intResponse = vbYes Then
                ' Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties()
                MsgBox(Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyComments))
                ' Call createXmlfile()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: try `ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdProperty).Value`

Comment: `wdPropertyComments` is a constant from the Word object library, so try `Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyComments`.  Or you can substitute the constant's value (5)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the `ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties` returns a DocumentProperties

More detail about this property [link:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196862.aspx)

`ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyWords)`